# Adding property observer to Decodable protocol in Swift 4

Tags: swift, decodable

I am retrieving a URL from a JSON parse, and upon doing that I would like to convert that URL into a UIImage.  Here is my current data struct:

```
struct Book: Decodable {
    let author: String
    let artworkURL: URL
    let genres: [Genre]
    let name: String
    let releaseDate: String
}
```

I tried to do:

```
struct Book: Decodable {
    let author: String
    var bookArtwork: UIImage
    let artworkURL: URL {
    didSet {
        do {
            if let imageData: Data = try Data(contentsOf: artworkURL) {
                bookArtwork = UIImage(data: imageData)!
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    let genres: [Genre]
    let name: String
    let releaseDate: String
}
```

But that `does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'`

Anyone else have a solution?

Comment: A couple problems with your code: (1) property observers are not triggered when the property is set in `init / init(from decoder:)` (2) a `let` property is a constant, so `didSet` is invalid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below I will enumerate a few ways of handling this sort of scenario, but the right answer is that you simply should not be retrieving images during the parsing of the JSON. And you definitely shouldn't be doing this synchronously (which is what `Data(contentsOf:)` does).

Instead, you should should only retrieve the images as they're needed by the UI. And you want to retrieve images into something that can be purged in low memory scenarios, responding to the `.UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning` system notification. Bottom line, images can take a surprising amount of memory if you're not careful and you almost always want to decouple the images from the model objects themselves.

---

But, if you're absolutely determined to incorporate the image into the `Book` object (which, again, I'd advise against), you can either:

1. You can make the `bookArtwork` a `lazy` variable:

   ```
   struct Book: Decodable {
       let author: String
       lazy var bookArtwork: UIImage = {
           let data = try! Data(contentsOf: artworkURL)
           return UIImage(data: data)!
       }()
       let artworkURL: URL
       let genres: [Genre]
       let name: String
       let releaseDate: String
   }
   ```

   This is horrible pattern in this case (again, because we should never do synchronous network call), but it illustrates the idea of a `lazy` variable. You sometimes do this sort of pattern with computed properties, too.
2. Just as bad (for the same reason, that synchronous network calls are evil), you can also implement a custom `init` method:

   ```
   struct Book: Decodable {
       let author: String
       let bookArtwork: UIImage
       let artworkURL: URL
       let genres: [Genre]
       let name: String
       let releaseDate: String

       init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
           let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
           author = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .author)
           artworkURL = try values.decode(URL.self, forKey: .artworkURL)
           genres = try values.decode([Genre].self, forKey: .genres)
           name = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
           releaseDate = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .releaseDate)

           // special processing for artworkURL
           let data = try Data(contentsOf: artworkURL)
           bookArtwork = UIImage(data: data)!
       }

       enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
           case author, artworkURL, genres, name, releaseDate
       }
   }
   ```

   In fact, this is even worse than the prior pattern, because at least with the first option, the synchronous network calls are deferred until when you reference the `UIImage` property.

   But for more information on this general pattern see *Encode and Decode Manually* in [Encoding and Decoding Custom Types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types).

I provide these two above patterns, as examples of how you can have some property not part of the JSON, but initialized in some other manner. But because you are using `Data(contentsOf:)`, neither of these are really advisable. But they're good patterns to be aware of in case the property in question didn't require some time consuming synchronous task, like you do here.

In this case, I think it's simplest to just provide a method to retrieve the image asynchronously when you need it:

3. Eliminate the synchronous network call altogether and just provide an asynchronous method to retrieve the image:

   ```
   struct Book: Decodable {
       let author: String
       let artworkURL: URL
       let genres: [Genre]
       let name: String
       let releaseDate: String

       func retrieveImage(completionHandler: @escaping (UIImage?, Error?) -> Void) {
           let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: artworkURL) { data, _, error in
               guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                   completionHandler(nil, error)
                   return
               }
               completionHandler(UIImage(data: data), nil)
           }
           task.resume()
       }
   }
   ```

   Then, when you need the image for your UI, you can retrieve it lazily:

   ```
   book.retrieveImage { image, error in
       DispatchQueue.main.async { image, error in
          cell.imageView.image = image
       }
   }
   ```

Those are a few approaches you can adopt.

Comment: Awesome man, you got me out of a huge doubt I had: _you simply should not be retrieving images during the parsing of the JSON_. I felt dirty because I had to use a separate class for the images but you're absolutely right, this should be a on-demand operation, not a serial one. Cheers 